# Trouble locating regex mistake

Tags: regex, python-3.x

```
import re

reg = r'^[(][+-]?([0]|([1-9][0-9]*)\.?\d+?),\s[+-]?([0]|([1-9][0-9]*)\.?\d+?)[)]$'
for _ in range(int(input())):
    coord = input()
    if re.search(reg, coord):
        if 0 <= float(re.search(reg, coord).group(1)) <= 90 and 0 <= float(re.search(reg, coord).group(3)) <= 180:
            print('Valid')
        else: print('Invalid')
    else: print('Invalid')
```

Here is my code for a regular expression that finds coordinates. I had trouble finding the mistake in the regular expression. The test cases that do not work are (-6, -165) and (-6, -172) What is the problem that prevents the code to enter the first if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that `\d+?` matches 1 or more digits, as few as possible, while you assumed it matches 0 or more digits.

To make `.xxx` part optional, use an optional non-capturing group `(?:\.\d+)?`:

```
^\([+-]?((?:0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?:\.\d+)?),\s[+-]?((?:0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?:\.\d+)?)\)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TfJ6lA/3)

The part that matches a number, `(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?:\.\d+)?`, now matches:

- `(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*)` - a non-capturing group matching either of the 2 alternatives:

  - `0` - a zero
  - `|` - or
  - `[1-9][0-9]*` - a digit from `1` to `9` and then any 0+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits.